# How to add column to existing information link

Tags: spotfire

How would I add a column to an existing information link?

If I add it to the SQL, it still doesn't show up in the element list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on whether or not the element is already there. But assuming it is not, when you open the information designer panel, click on New => Columnn (or on the right click on Column under create elements. You will see all the available datasources. Go to the sql table where the column is located, add this column to the column element. Save the Column element in the correct folder. Then open the information link and add the just created element to the information link.